# Can Postman be used with GOST SSL?

Tags: postman, gost3410

First, I am not a developer, so I apologize if I don't get this right. I need to send json to a Russian application that uses GOST SSL (GET and POST). I am using the Postman v7.36.1 Windows client. Is it possible to do this?

If not, is there a different Windows client that would allow me to use GOST SSL?